# Exact Match using VBA Replace

Tags: regex, vba, excel, replace, pattern-matching

I am trying to remove a string from another string using VBA replace function.

The string from which I am trying to remove looks like below which contains cell address concatenated by `;`

`"$B$1;$B$21;$B$2;$C$3;$B$20;$B$201"`

and the string which I would like to remove is `$B$2` by say xxx.

The replace function matches all occurrences of `$B$2` in the string and gives me the output as below

`$B$1;xxx1;xxx;$C$3;xxx0;xxx01`

However I would like to search for `$B$2` exactly in the string and expect an output like

`$B$1;$B$21;xxx;$C$3;$B$20;$B$201`

I one way I could think of doing this is by splitting up the string on `;`(separator and looping and looking at each value) but I am looking at more direct solution here. Like using pattern matching techniques or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the following `;` in the replace operation, to make sure you only match "complete" references. You just need to take a precaution for also matching the last entry, by adding a dummy semicolon at the end:

```
s = "$B$1;$B$21;$B$2;$C$3;$B$20;$B$201"
find = "$B$2"
repl = "xxxx"
result = Replace(s & ";", find & ";", repl & ";")
result = Left(result, Len(result)-1) ' Remove the final semicolon
```

Although this works for your case, in a more general exercise, you would also want to test for the *preceding* delimiter, and then the last two lines would look like this:

```
result = Replace(";" & s & ";", ";" & find & ";", ";" & repl & ";")
result = Mid(result, 2, Len(result)-2)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a beautiful solution

Answer (score 2):

you cold use:

```
Function myReplace(strng As String, findStr As String, replacementStrng As String)
    myReplace = Replace(strng & ";", findStr & ";", replacementStrng & ";")
    myReplace = Left(myReplace, Len(myReplace) - 1)
End Function
```

to be exploited in your "main" sub like follows:

```
strng = "$B$1;$B$21;$B$2;$C$3;$B$20;$B$201"
MsgBox myReplace(strng, "$B$2", "xxx")
```